# How do I disable corpses?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

I've read on the Darkest Dungeon forums that there's an option to turn off the corpses being left behind after you kill an enemy. I can't seem to find that option anywhere in the options menu, though. Where is it?

Comment: But.. but.. but... then you deprive yourself of the pleasure of seeing three corpses between you and your last target then realizing you don't have any ranged attacks on the last guy in your party who has an action remaining! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I almost deleted this question, since I found the answer a minute later and feel like a dolt, but it is in the options menu. It's just that you actually have to be in a campaign to see those options. If you're on the main title screen, you don't see them.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the correct one.  It's appropriate as long as the question and answer are potentially useful to other people.  (This one qualifies IMO)